# Missing view.context or templateContext in an Ember event handler

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js, dom-events

I'm trying to push the object that populated a view into an array, but the reference is somehow getting lost. I've got an Ember view, with a defined `eventManager`:

```
FrontLine.NewProductButton = Em.View.extend({
    tagName: 'button',
    classNames: ['addtl_product',],
    templateName: 'product-button',
    eventManager: Ember.Object.create({
        click: function(event, view) {
            FrontLine.ProductsController.toggleProductToCustomer(event, view);
        }
    })
})
```

That view renders a bunch of buttons that are rendered with properties that come from objects in the `ProductsController` using the `#each` helper. That part works great. And when I click on any of those buttons, the click event is firing and doing whatever I ask, including successfully calling the handler function (`toggleProductToCustomer`) I've designated from my `ProductsController`:

```
FrontLine.ProductsController = Em.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    newProduct: function(productLiteral) {
        this.pushObject(productLiteral);
    },
    toggleProductToCustomer: function(event, view){
        FrontLine.CustomersController.currentCustomer.productSetAdditional.pushObject(view.context);    
    }
});
```

I'm trying to use that function to push the object whose properties populated that view into an array. Another place in my app (a simple search field), that works perfectly well, using `pushObject(view.context)`. Here, however, all that gets pushed into the array is `undefined`. I tried using [view.templateContext](http://docs.emberjs.com/symbols/Ember.View.html#templateContext) instead, but that doesn't work any better. When I try console.log-ing the button's `view` object from inside those functions, I get what I'd expect:

```
<(subclass of FrontLine.NewProductButton):ember623>
```

But either `view.context` or `view.templateContext` return `undefined`. How do I access the object I'm after, so I can add it to my array?

Comment: What happens if you use the get() function instead of direct access your properties ?

Comment: get() is definitely essential for Ember, but how would you use it on view.context, as that's what I'm having trouble accessing?

Comment: view.get('context') does'nt work ? Perhaps I'm simply not understanding

Comment: Nope, it doesn't/didn't. See answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that it was one letter's difference:

```
view.content
```

or:

```
view.get('content')
```

provides the source object in that particular situation, rather than `view.context`.

(My only real challenge with Ember so far is that accessors for objects and properties vary so much from situation to situation, and there's no real documentation for that. Sometimes the object is at view.context, sometimes it's at view.content, sometimes _parentView.content, etc., etc. It would be awesome if there were a chart with the umpteen different syntaxes for accessing the same data, depending on which particular aperture you're reaching through to get it. I'm still discovering them...)

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle of your code, with the template and js code ? Usually, you can retrieve the context object from the event, with event.context. But you're right, it's not always easy to know where the context comes from.